# How to get get URL of new page using casperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, window.open

I am using casperJS to get links when clicking a button. The links are returned with window.open in javaScript.

**The code I have written logs all the pages after clicking button, but phantom is not exiting in terminal window. Also some pages only show about:blank, especially the last ones.**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var page = require('webpage').create();

var address = 'http://www.example.com';

page.open(address, function() {

    page.onPageCreated = function(newPage) {

        newPage.onClosing = function(closingPage) {
            console.log('A child page is closing: ' + closingPage.url);

            /* if i set phantom.exit() it will only log the first page url. 
            Problem: I need all page urls. */
        }

    }

    page.evaluate(function() {
        $(".button").click();
    });

}
```

Comment: Maybe the about:blank cause phantom to not exit.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're clicking a button (`$(".button").click();`) which opens a new popup/window (`newPage`) which should contain a list (in `newPage` content) of URLs and you're trying to log them. I don't see where you're trying to retrieve it in your script. It also seems to me that `newPage` is actually `closingPage`. What does the URL of the popup have to do with the URL list in the content of the popup. Please [edit] your question to make it more clear. Also, why are you writing PhantomJS code if you can use CasperJS code?

Answer (score 2):

The method "getCurrentUrl()" will return the current url. Here is an easy (not really meaningful) example:

```
casper.test.begin('My Test', 1 , function suite(test) {

        casper.start().viewport(1600,1000).thenOpen("https://blabla.de", function() {
                var mylink = this.getElementInfo("#linkid").text;
                this.clickLabel(mylink);
        });

        casper.waitForSelector("#page2", function() {
                this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
        });

        casper.run(function() {
                test.done();
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL of the current page in CasperJS using one of the following methods:

- [`casper.getCurrentUrl()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getcurrenturl):

  - Retrieves the current page URL. Note that the URL will be URL-decoded.
- [`casper.page.url`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/url.html):

  - Accesses the existing PhantomJS WebPage instance ([page](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#page)), and gets the current URL of the web page.
- [`casper.evaluate(function () { return location.href; })`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

  - Evaluates the page URL in the Page DOM Environment.