# open the url, when .click() is performed using casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

i use the url "x" and find the next page button and perform .click() even on it. The .click() event is working fine and i found no errors with it. How can i make casperjs to redirect to the next page when .click() is performed. I thought of using casper.open() but couldn't find a way to use it combined with .click()

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('url');

casper.then(function() {                                 
    if (this.exists('a.j-pagination-next')) {  //selector for the next page button

        this.click('a.j-pagination-next');   // Click on next page  button
         //should return the next page url 
        // this.open()
    }
    else{
        console.log("No such selector")  //end of pages or wrong selector 
    }
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you click the link, CasperJS will open the next page, no need to an extra `open()` call. You need to use `then()` or a `waitFor*()` function to perform the next step on the next page.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('url');

casper.then(function() {                                 
    if (this.exists('a.j-pagination-next')) {  //selector for the next page button

        this.click('a.j-pagination-next');   // Click on next page  button
    }
    else{
        console.log("No such selector")  //end of pages or wrong selector 
    }
});

casper.then(fucntion(){
   console.log("I'm on the next page now");
});

casper.run();
```

**EDIT**

In order to get the current URL you should call `this.getCurrentUrl()`:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('url');

casper.then(function() {                                 
    if (this.exists('a.j-pagination-next')) {  //selector for the next page button

        this.click('a.j-pagination-next');   // Click on next page  button
    }
    else{
        console.log("No such selector")  //end of pages or wrong selector 
    }
});

casper.then(fucntion(){
   console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

Take a look at [How to get get URL of new page using casperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696904/how-to-get-get-url-of-new-page-using-casperjs)

Comment: how to get the url of the next page which is opened after .click() is perfromed. I tried using waitfor() and included .getcurrentpageurl() inside the waitfor function fter the .click is performed. But its returning the first page url itself. Can you suggest me how to get the nextpage(second page) url.